# Under what conditions can two classes have different average values, yet be indistinguishable to a SVM?

Tags: svm

I am asking because I have observed sometimes in neuroimaging that a brain region might have different average activation between two experimental conditions, but sometimes an SVM classifier somehow can't distinguish the patterns of activation between the two conditions.

My intuition is that this might happen in cases where the within-class variance is far greater than the between-class variance. For example, suppose we have two classes, A and B, and that for simplicity our data consists just of integers (rather than vectors). Let the data falling under class A be 0,0,0,0,0,10,10,10,10,10. Let the data falling under class B be 1,1,1,1,1,11,11,11,11,11. Here, A and B are clearly different on average, yet there's no decision boundary that would allow A and B to be distinguished. I *believe* this logic would hold even if our data consisted of vectors, rather than integers.

Is this a special case of some broader range of cases where an SVM would fail to distinguish two classes that are different on average? Is it possible to delineate the precise conditions under which an SVM classifier would fail to distinguish two classes that differ on average?

EDIT: Assume a linear SVM.

Comment: in short - there are no such conditions. (nonlinear) SVM can distinguish **any** set of points. No matter how complex. It might not generalise well, but distinguish in terms of getting 0 training error - will be always achieved (as long as there are no two points with the same label, but this does not matter either way)

Comment: Good point. What if we stick to a linear SVM?

Comment: Then it can separate iff data is linearly separable, like any other linear classifier. Just crank up "C" constant in SVM to very big values, and every linearly separable dataset will be separated just fine (in original formulation of "hard margin SVM" there is no C, it is equivalent to having C=infinity)

Answer (score 0):

As described in the comments - there are no such conditions because SVM will separate data just fine (I am not talking about any generalisation here, just separating training data). For the rest of the answer I am assuming there are no two identical points with different labels.

#### Non-linear case

For a kernel case, using something like RBF kernel, SVM will always perfectly separate any training set, given that C is big enough.

#### Linear case

If data is linearly separable then again - with big enough C it will separate data just fine. If data is not linearly separable, cranking up C as much as possible will lead to smaller and smaller training error (of course it will not get 0 since data is not linearly separable).

In particular for the data you provided kernelized SVM will get 100%, and **any** linear model will get 50%, but it has nothing to do with means being different or variances relations - it is simply a dataset where any linear separator has at most 50% accuracy, literally every decision point, thus it has nothing to do with SVM. In particular it will separate them "in the middle", meaning that the decision point will be somewhere around "5".